# Identifying a children's fantasy book series (gem-based powers, sea monsters attacking tower)

Tags: story-identification, magic, childrens-novel

There's this children's fantasy series I've been trying to find for years from one book I've read in my youth. From what I recall it was a long-ish series (7-8 books?) and I *believe* that the powers in the books were based on gems, or some kind of stones. I read this series about 8-7 years ago and it was finished by then - hopefully that gives a rough time period for people to pin it too.

I know the one book I read was either the last or near last book in the series, and the only part of the plot I can vividly remember were incredibly large sea monsters arriving from the ocean/sea to attack some sort of...tower? I believe there were also illustrations of these monsters (though I'm not sure if I'm not just mistaking those illustrations for my imagination).

I think I also recall a segment about a character trying to escape some sort of mine, where there were Underseers/Overseers, though that may not have been in this same book (I don't remember if I only read one or two books of the series, haha). I also remember there being some sort of love story if that's any help (probably not).

Sorry this is so vague, and I hope someone can give me an answer eventually! It's been really bugging me, and I can't seem to find any series like it anywhere.

Comment: Hello Tonmoy, welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack Exchange and thank you for your question. Have you seen this one? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33479/19561 Could that be the one?

Comment: Ooooh, I think this is the one. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: In that case, I'll mark this question as a duplicate of that one. Please remember that that's not a bad thing, it just makes it easier for people to find the right answer.